# JavaScript, CSS selectors and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

Anybody know, how work CSS selectors in JS like :not() in ie8-9? I think it will not work in simple JS, But how it will work, if you will use jQuery or prototype? Is it implemented in this libraries?

as an example:

```
$("div:not('.mydiv')")
```

Unfortunatly, I have no ie8-9, so I can't test it by self.

Comment: You are asking just for ask or are you having a real problem with this?

Comment: if the selector is not supported in those browser then using the above will still fail, not sure about using .not() as apposed to :not though

Comment: I ask for asking. I think it is depend from javascript engine implementation, not from browser css selectors support.

Comment: Your example uses jQuery, which has its own selector engine ([Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/)). It will provide support for `:not()` even if the browser itself does not support it (provided you use the appropriate jQuery branch -- 1.x to support IE8 and lower).

Comment: If your `$` is a reference to `jQuery`, then it will work, because the library works around cross-browser differences. In vanilla JS `document.querySelector("div:not(.myDiv)")` works in IE9, but not in IE8. Basic support for `:not()` was implemented in IE9: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 0):

Use this to test different IE versions: https://www.modern.ie/

**edit:** There are some VMs provided officially by MS to test different versions of Internet Explorer from version 6 to 11 (at the moment of posting).

And e.g. this for browser support: http://caniuse.com/

Comment: I does not trust to that services, because nothing can't emulate ie. Unfortunatly.

Comment: That's partially true but you might get a first insight. For actual testing VMs might help - these can be downloaded on the WebSite I posted above: https://www.modern.ie/de-de/virtualization-tools#downloads

These virtual versions are officially provided by MS...